# RTL8188CTV dosen't work, firmware issues and inconsistent symptoms

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, firmware, realtek

I'm working on a laptop that has a WonderMedia 8650 cpu, that was shipped with android 2.2 from factory, and thanks to this [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/vt8500-wm8505-linux-kernel), this [github repo](https://github.com/linux-wmt/linux-vtwm) and this custom [debian 11](https://github.com/wh0/bookconfig) setup, I was able to boot debian 11 running kernel 5.15. Most of the issues are sorted out (Ethernet, keyboard, mousepad, gpio, screen, serial console), but I cant seem to fin anythin to fix the issues I'm having with the internal USB WiFi adapter.

Internally, this laptop has soldered a USB Realtek RTL8188CTV WiFi adapter, that can be turned on or off using an internal GPIO pin. I can succesfully toggle that GPIO pin, the Kernel can succesfully detect the device (lsusb: `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter`), but I cannot use the device because "i dont know"(?). The debian installation is being set up using [multistrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap), and it installs `firmware-realtek`, wich is needed for the adapter to work. Now, here comes the issue.

After the first boot, I get some messages on dmesg that seem to tell me that the device is working properly, but after some time of it trying to connect to the network, it fails and then it starts to error out, making the system unstable and unresponsive. The only way to revert this is by "unplugging" (turning off the GPIO) the adapter. Here is the dmesg for that situation:

```
[ 1116.320000] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-platform
[ 1116.550000] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[ 1116.660000] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[ 1116.660000] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[ 1116.670000] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[ 1116.670000] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[ 1116.930000] rtl8192cu 1-4:1.0 wlxc4604401a0a3: renamed from wlan0
[ 1117.260000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 1117.400000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 1118.590000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 1118.630000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 1188.850000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 1188.900000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 1196.630000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f
[ 1196.700000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 1196.700000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticated
[ 1196.750000] wlxc4604401a0a3: associate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 1196.770000] wlxc4604401a0a3: RX AssocResp from e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1196.880000] wlxc4604401a0a3: associated
[ 1202.870000] wlxc4604401a0a3: deauthenticated from e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[ 1208.290000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f
[ 1208.360000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 1209.040000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 2/3)
[ 1210.060000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 3/3)
[ 1211.040000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authentication with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f timed out
[ 1212.770000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f
[ 1212.830000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 1214.060000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 2/3)
[ 1215.040000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 3/3)
[ 1216.080000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authentication with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f timed out
[ 1218.290000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f
[ 1218.350000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 1219.040000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 2/3)
[ 1220.080000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 3/3)
[ 1221.020000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authentication with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f timed out
[ 1232.500000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f
[ 1232.580000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 1233.030000] wlxc4604401a0a3: aborting authentication with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1233.500000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 1233.540000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 1236.320000] rtl_usb: reg 0x4, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x2d2d2d00
[ 1236.390000] rtl_usb: reg 0x4, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x2d2d2d00
[ 1236.450000] rtl_usb: reg 0x4, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x0
[ 1236.710000] rtl_usb: reg 0x4, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x40000104
[ 1240.820000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 1375.350000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 1518.700000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1519.590000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1520.200000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1521.130000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1522.160000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1523.280000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1524.280000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1525.350000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1526.550000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1527.810000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1528.920000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1529.690000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1530.320000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1532.000000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1532.020000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1532.630000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1532.650000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1533.300000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1533.320000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1533.930000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1533.950000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1534.560000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1534.580000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1535.400000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1535.410000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1536.280000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1536.300000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1536.910000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1536.930000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1537.580000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1537.600000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1538.210000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1538.230000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1538.840000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1538.860000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1539.510000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1539.520000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1540.140000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1540.160000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1550.510000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 1685.170000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 1837.690000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1838.330000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1838.940000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1839.570000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1840.230000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1840.840000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1841.460000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1842.260000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1843.290000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1843.900000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1844.900000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1845.590000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1846.360000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 1855.510000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 1984.330000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2128.050000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2128.660000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2129.290000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2129.900000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2130.900000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2131.590000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2132.360000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2133.390000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2134.020000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2135.000000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2135.720000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2136.490000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2137.520000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2139.190000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2139.820000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2140.540000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2141.540000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2142.180000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2143.040000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2144.060000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2145.170000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2146.170000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2147.240000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2148.340000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2149.510000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2150.780000] rtl_usb: Urb has error status 0xFFFFFFB9
[ 2160.860000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2291.410000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2310.220000] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 2349.170000] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-platform
[ 2349.400000] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[ 2349.510000] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[ 2349.520000] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[ 2349.530000] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[ 2349.540000] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[ 2349.750000] rtl8192cu 1-4:1.0 wlxc4604401a0a3: renamed from wlan0
[ 2350.070000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2350.200000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2351.340000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2351.380000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2354.350000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2354.400000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2356.670000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f
[ 2356.730000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 2356.770000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticated
[ 2356.780000] wlxc4604401a0a3: associate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[ 2356.810000] wlxc4604401a0a3: RX AssocResp from e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 2356.960000] wlxc4604401a0a3: associated
[ 2357.950000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlxc4604401a0a3: link becomes ready
[ 2403.100000] wlxc4604401a0a3: deauthenticating from e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2403.420000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2403.460000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2428.870000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2428.920000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2458.910000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7
[ 2458.980000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 1/3)
[ 2460.070000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 2/3)
[ 2461.040000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 3/3)
[ 2462.020000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authentication with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 timed out
[ 2463.400000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7
[ 2463.480000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 1/3)
[ 2464.010000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 2/3)
[ 2465.040000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 3/3)
[ 2466.010000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authentication with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 timed out
[ 2467.720000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7
[ 2467.800000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 1/3)
[ 2469.040000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 2/3)
[ 2470.010000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 3/3)
[ 2471.030000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authentication with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 timed out
[ 2473.270000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7
[ 2473.330000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 1/3)
[ 2474.080000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 2/3)
[ 2475.020000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 (try 3/3)
[ 2476.050000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authentication with ae:8e:29:4b:c5:c7 timed out
[ 2483.490000] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 2483.510000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2483.510000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
```

In this case, I've tried to connect multiple times to different networks, all of them resulted in a fail.

Now this becomes a little bit weird. After the previous try, I rebooted two or three times, and I got different messages from dmesg:

```
[   73.020000] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-platform
[   73.250000] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[   73.370000] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   73.370000] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   73.370000] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   73.370000] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   73.740000] rtl8192cu 1-4:1.0 wlxc4604401a0a3: renamed from wlan0
[   74.070000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc4604401a0a3: link is not ready
[   74.070000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   74.180000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   74.600000] rtl8192c_common: chksum report fail! REG_MCUFWDL:0x00030000 .
[   74.600000] rtl8192c_common: Firmware is not ready to run!
[   74.970000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc4604401a0a3: link is not ready
[   75.360000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   75.390000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   75.770000] rtl8192c_common: chksum report fail! REG_MCUFWDL:0x00030000 .
[   75.770000] rtl8192c_common: Firmware is not ready to run!
[   76.130000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc4604401a0a3: link is not ready
[   76.970000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc4604401a0a3: link is not ready
[   78.900000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   78.930000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   79.260000] rtl8192c_common: chksum report fail! REG_MCUFWDL:0x00030000 .
[   79.260000] rtl8192c_common: Firmware is not ready to run!
[   79.630000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc4604401a0a3: link is not ready
[   81.190000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f
[   81.250000] wlxc4604401a0a3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[   81.260000] wlxc4604401a0a3: authenticated
[   81.310000] wlxc4604401a0a3: associate with e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (try 1/3)
[   81.370000] wlxc4604401a0a3: RX AssocResp from e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   81.480000] wlxc4604401a0a3: associated
[   81.580000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlxc4604401a0a3: link becomes ready
[  128.080000] wlxc4604401a0a3: deauthenticating from e4:c3:2a:d9:87:7f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  128.450000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[  128.490000] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[  128.850000] rtl8192c_common: chksum report fail! REG_MCUFWDL:0x00030000 .
[  128.850000] rtl8192c_common: Firmware is not ready to run!
[  129.220000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc4604401a0a3: link is not ready
[  129.420000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc4604401a0a3: link is not ready
[  131.430000] rtl_usb: reg 0x4, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x4d5
[  131.470000] rtl_usb: reg 0x4, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x3902d2a
[  131.520000] rtl_usb: reg 0x21, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x2d2d2d00
[  131.570000] rtl_usb: reg 0x0, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffb9 value=0x2d2d2d00
[  132.170000] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
```

From then, it gets really inconsistent. Sometimes it does the same thing as the first boot, sometimes it does the avobe, and sometimes it just makes the system unresponsive and dosent even tries to connect.

I dont know if this has to do with me building the kernel with missing stuff, or maybe is realtek being realtek on linux. I dont really know what to do. In any case, here is my kernel [.config](https://gist.github.com/ffpp2003/ab161b0b99e447dc13306334ab321ec2)